# How to link map to a timeline using Odyssey.js

Tags: cartography

Background info of our project:
we are trying to do a vertical timeline that is linked to a map and story for web. Visuals are attached. [image][image][image]

We are using this plugin, http://cartodb.github.io/odyssey.js/ as of now. Is it possible to incorporate timeline functionality on top of this plugin? if so, how? (we have seen torque tool, we are looking for the map to move with the timeline) Also is it possible to remove the map while retaining marker placements?